# Custom pipe not converting string into Dom Element

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular6, angular-pipe

I created a custom pipe in angular 6 to convert string into HTMLDom Element(tag), I can able to get the response in my ts file but in html it is showing as `[object Element]`

```
{{link.portfolioCompanyLinkName.svGicons | quillConvertToDom }}
```

My custom pipe Ts file

```
export class QuillConvertToDomPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    var xmlString = value;
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"); 
    console.info(doc.firstChild);
    return doc.firstChild;
  }

}
```

when i console i am receiving the value

[image]

Comment: @AdritaSharma https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmempw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `innerHtml` instead of a pipe.

Try this:

```
<div [innerHtml]="tag"></div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxjntk)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace 
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

with below line
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/html");